# Building documentation for emberjs

Tags: ember.js

With what tool I can build a documentation from sources of emberjs? 
JSDoc3 failing with 'The @private tag does not permit a value.'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Yuidoc](http://yui.github.com/yuidoc/). There's `docs` directory (under root). If you `cd` there from the terminal and run `yuidoc --server` (assuming that you have it installed), you will be able to view auto-generated docs at `localhost:3000`.

Comment: Works like a charm except for ember-data: its comments has invalid formatting indeed.